# .first gives error when there's only none/one image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multiple images uploader, and I'm showing the images on the page, like this:

```
<%= image_tag product.images.first %>
```

This works fine as long as a product has multiple images, but it gives the error "nil is not a valid asset source" when there's only 1 image. I know I could check for multiple images like this:

```
<%= image_tag product.images.first if @product.images.present? %>
```

But IF there is 1 image, I do want that one image to show up on the page. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
<%= image_tag product.images.first if @product.images.present? else image_tag product.image if @product.image.present? %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) would help here:

```
<%= image_tag product.images.any? ? product.images.first : product.image %>
```

or even simpler, using logical OR operator, as @mudasobwa noticed:

```
<%= image_tag product.images.first || product.image %>
```

Comment: `product.images.first || product.image`?

Comment: Right, believe or not, it came to me just before you wrote your comment. :)

Comment: This worked like a charm! I knew there was some syntax for it, but I'm quite new to rails and couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Jakeroo _sidenote:_ this syntax (the logical part inside markup tags) has nothing to do with rails, this is plain ruby.